# Таблица со скроллом

Tags: прокрутка

Сделал я таблицу со скроллингом.как сделать так чтобы первый столбец оставался статичным.то есть не поддавался скроллингу?Это в html с css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотрите фремворк jQuery - там есть такая таблица  см [тут](http://www.jqueryscripts.ru/scripts/jquery_table/jqgrid/)

Comment: сделал сам)))
создал две таблицы
одна прокручивается другая нет
объявил в css как два блока присобачил и все получилось